# composeExtensions functions in MS teams bot not working on iOS teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a fully working bot within Microsoft Teams, and in Teams-in-the-browser and all Teams Apps 'flavours' **EXCEPT iOS**, switching between Opportunities/Companies/Cases etc. works as intended (i.e. a different search is executed in the back end, and the results are returned).

In iOS, the compose extension selected by default (in my case Opportunities) works fine, however changing the selected compose extension (Companies, Cases etc.) doesn't change the results coming from the back end.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour? Is it a bug in the iOS implementation of Teams?

[image: In Teams-in-the-browser and all Teams Apps 'flavours' EXCEPT iOS, switching between Opportunities/Companies/Cases etc. works as intended]

App manifest, as requested:

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.3",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "id": "{{ appid }}",
    "packageName": "{{ packagename }}",
    "developer": {
        "name": "{{ name }}",
        "websiteUrl": "{{ website }}",
        "privacyUrl": "{{ privacy }}",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "{{ terms }}"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "{{ shortname }}",
        "full": "{{ fullname }}"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "{{ shortdescr}}",
        "full": "{{ fulldescr }}"
    },
    "icons": {
        "outline": "logo32x32.png",
        "color": "logo192x192.png"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "{{ packagename }}",
            "name": "Dashboard",
            "contentUrl": "{{ appurl }}/dashboard",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "{{ appurl }}/configure",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "scopes": [
                "team"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "{{ botid }}",
            "needsChannelSelector": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "{{ botid }}",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "searchOpportunities",
                    "description": "Search the Opportunities",
                    "title": "Opportunities",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "searchOppo",
                            "description": "Search the Opportunities",
                            "title": "Opportunities"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "searchCompanies",
                    "description": "Search the Companies",
                    "title": "Companies",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "searchComp",
                            "description": "Search the Companies",
                            "title": "Companies"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "searchCases",
                    "description": "Search the Cases",
                    "title": "Cases",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "searchCase",
                            "description": "Search the Cases",
                            "title": "Cases"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "searchPeople",
                    "description": "Search the People",
                    "title": "People",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "searchPers",
                            "description": "Search the People",
                            "title": "People"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "{{ appurl }}"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you  please provide your app manifest so we can test it at our end for iOS device? That is not the intended behavior

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT - I edited the question to include the manifest.json for the app

Comment: Thanks In meantime I will check it and let you know

Comment: We can reproduce this as a Bug for iOS mobile. Thanks for your concern. We will get back to you once Bug is resolved

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT - any update on a timescale for the fix? My customer is delaying launch of the Teams app until it works properly on iPhone. Thanks